# String concatenation in bash 3.2.57 (macOS)

Tags: string, bash, macos, concatenation

My goal is to concatenate two strings.

Here's a copy-paste of my bash script:

```
str1="Hello"
str2="World"
str3=$str1$str2
echo $str3
```

The expected output is `HelloWorld` but I'm getting `World` instead.

It works fine when I run it in the terminal.

Here's the output when I run `cat -v` on my script:

```
str1="Hello"^M
str2="World"^M
str3=$str1$str2^M
echo $str3^M
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Doesn't the definition of `str1` end with a windows line-end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's probably because you have a carriage return (`\r`) at the end of `$str1`. I'm getting the same output with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
str1="Hello"$'\r'
str2="World"
str3=$str1$str2
echo $str3
```

It often happens when you create the script on a MSWin machine.

It prints Hello, but then `\r` moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line, and overwrites the Hello with World.

You can verify it by running it through a hex dump or `cat -v`.

Comment: Thanks, see the updated question with the output of `cat -v`.

Comment: @EtienneMartin: Yes, that's it. Remove the carriage returns.

Comment: You're the man @choroba, changing the line endings to unix in my editor fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! Been stuck on this for over an hour